# UPDATE & SELECT запрос не работает

Tags: php, mysql

Хочу что б оновлялись 3 поля соответвующие строке в которой будет пропуск 0006 и максимальный ид, все в одной таблице.
Собственно:

```
    <?php
require_once 'connection.php';

// Create connection

$conn = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $password, $database);
mysqli_query($conn,"SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
mysqli_query($conn,"SET SESSION collation_connection ='utf8_unicode_ci'");


// Check connection

if (!$conn) {
      die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

echo "Connected successfully";
$datey = date('Y-m-d');
$datev = date('H:i:s');
$sql ="UPDATE prohod SET (status = '0', time_vih="$datev", date_vih = "$datey") WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM prohod WHERE propusk=0006 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
      echo "Update successfully";
} else {
      echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Comment: `syntax error, unexpected '$datev' (T_VARIABLE)`. Замените кавычки вокруг переменных на одинарные....

Comment: Connected successfullyError: UPDATE prohod SET (status = '0', time_vih='16:28:09', date_vih = '2019-06-10') WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM prohod WHERE propusk=0006 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(status = '0', time_vih='16:28:09', date_vih = '2019-06-10') WHERE id = (SELECT ' at line 1

Comment: Список присвоений в предложении SET не должен быть обрамлён скобками.

Comment: Connected successfullyError: UPDATE prohod SET status = '0', time_vih='16:40:59', date_vih = '2019-06-10' WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM prohod WHERE propusk=0006 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)
Table 'prohod' is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data

Comment: Как то разделить надо на две таблицы?

Comment: С построением запроса в PHP разобрались, синтаксических претензий нет. Вопрос решён. Теперь нужно построить логически правильный запрос в MySQL - а это совсем иная задача. Создайте новый вопрос, но уже без PHP-кода.

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!!!!!